# react-router-dom layout rendered multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using React 18 and react-router-dom 6

Every route I visit will have this problem right now where my layout renders an  outlet which renders the layout again.

I'm looking at their [docs](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) and the first layout example shows the layout is **outside** of the `App` route, when I try this my `App` component doesn't render but they show the component tree below as having the App.

`src/index.js`

```js
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<App />}>
          <Route element={<Layout />}>
            <Route index element={<Home />} />
            <Route path="/launches" element={<Launches />} />
            <Route path="/launches/:id" element={<OneLaunch />} />
            <Route path="*" element={<NotFound />} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <TopNav />
      <Layout />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

This is the only place I'm using `<Outlet />`, I verified with find all in project.

```js
export const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <p>layout view</p>
      <Outlet />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Attached is my component tree when I go to the home route with `localhost:3000` in the address bar. It looks the same when I go to any other route, just replace `Home` with the other component in the tree.

I can see that first `Layout` is rendered by `App` and the other nested one is rendered by `createRoot`

[image: component tree at home route]

Answer (score 1):

If the `App` component is to also be used as a layout route component then it needs to render an `Outlet` component for any nested routes it is rendering.

Instead of rendering the `Layout` is should render `Outlet` in its place.

Example:

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Fragment>
      <TopNav />
      <Outlet />
    </Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed in the component tree dev tools that the app rendered the first layout but then the `createRoot` rendered the 2nd layout and remembered hearing about each parent using an outlet.

The fix was to change the app to use `<Outlet />` instead of `Layout` and keep the `<Outlet />` in the layout as well.